# Multiple Docks on the same screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Is it possible to have multiple Docks on the same screen?

Like, one on the bottom, one on the left, and another on the right?

Comment: Do you want the dock's to be different or just the same to open from all sides?

Comment: I'm intrigued... What is the use-case for this?

Comment: @KevinGrabher I want them to be different

Comment: @Joonas I feel that my dock is too crowded, yet I want those apps on the dock. Plus, I can categorise the apps onto different docks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have multiple native macOS Docks. There are Dock alternatives however, some which support multiple Docks and others that support just more organization. Compatibility is very much dependent on your version of macOS.
One alternative that seems to work with macOS High Sierra is [uBar](https://brawersoftware.com/products/ubar).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really trying to answer the question, I'm just trying to give alternatives, so that you could maybe fix the underlying issue another way.

---

I'm thinking, even if it was possible to do what you want, maybe folders would be a better solution. If that sound like a good idea, check out [**Station**](http://www.truenorthsoftware.com/station/):

[image]

---

---

---

I feel Station is probably the thing that solves your problem with the Dock, but just in case, here's some more thoughts on the matter:

How about application launchers? They could offer some help...

I personally only have open apps in the dock and I use different ways to launch applications, but most often I use [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/). If application launching is all you want to do, Spotlight can nowadays do it pretty well. Default shortcut for Spotligh is `cmd+space`.

The way I would open application using Alfred is this...

Let's say I want to open Photoshop:

1. `Ctrl + Space` opens a little windows, much like Spotlight, where you can write
2. I start writing `Pho`... and at that point it already thinks I want to open Photoshop so then I launch it by pressing enter.

If I want to open Illustrator I do the same thing except I write `Ill` and press enter.

I find this way more handy than drowning my dock in application icons.

---

I'll mention this just for fun... It is relevant, it's just maybe a bit of an overkill for most people. So, [Elgato Stream Deck](https://www.elgato.com/en/gaming/stream-deck) is basically... a macro keyboard with lcd screens on each key meant for streamers. I bought one for myself for general productivity stuff... You can assign keys to open applications and trigger hotkeys, which I would say are the two main things you can do with it in terms of the Actions it can perform. It also supports infinite nested folders, which is amazing. Well it might be a bit silly and expensive for most people, like I said, but it's an option....

This is not my picture, but it think it shows the potential of this thing being an application launcher.

[image]

A big hurdle for me and my use case with this thing is that it doesn't support launching scripts, so for most of what I have done with it, I've had to use the "trigger a shortcut" action and then I've made Alfred workflows to launch scripts using that same shortcut. So basically when I press a key in ESD, it sends a set shortcut combination to the OS, Alfred detects it and triggers a script...